# Injecting data inside another function

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to understand something new about WordPress Gutemberg blocks, and I've found a snippet of code that I do not fully understand.

I believe this code injects the returned data inside another function, but I'll be glad to have a some confirmation.

Code looks like the following one. I just need to know if the function withSelect() injects its data inside the anonymous function.

I've never used a syntax like function foo( .... return x; )( function(x) )

My fault, I know!

```
var  withSelect = wp.data.withSelect;

registerBlockType( 'my-plugin/latest-post', {
    // something
    edit: withSelect( function(select) {
        //do something
        return { posts: .... };
    }) ( function (props) {
        if (props.posts){
           // do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Reference: https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripped down to its very basics:

```
withSelect( function(){ ... } ) ( function() { ... } )
```

This is the same as:

```
var anonFunction1 = function() { ... };
var anonfunction2 = function() { ... };
var callable = withSelect( anonFunction1 );
var results = callable( anonFunction2 );
```

Based on the documentation, `withSelect` uses the provided function to generate a new function, which it returns.